# Advanced Custom Fields checkbox inside repeater

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to use checkbox inside a repeater field to show different images. If user checks "chicken" and "roast" it must display two images to front-end. If nothing is checked, nothing is displayed.

I have tried the [Advanced Custom Fields](http://advancedcustomfields.com) documentation and all I can get is NULL or exactly these names "chicken" and "roast" to front-end. This is my piece of code that is inside repeater loop.

```
<?php if (get_field('selection') == 'chicken') { ?>

 //some piece of code

<?php } else if (get_field('selection') == 'roast') { ?> 

 //some more code  

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A checkbox creates a list of check-able items. In other words, you need to check that your string is in an `array()`. For example:

```
if( in_array( 'chicken', get_field('field_name') ) ) {
    //...
}
```

Read more about checkboxes in the ACF codex: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/checkbox/

Comment: Yes! 100% my fault, that solution was clear as a whistle. I just didn't understood it correctly on ACF page. :)